# Is this approach bad practice (memory leaking?)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have created a class that extends Android's `WebViewClient` so I can make it a 'preview' only client - i.e. most navigation is not allowed.

When a user tries to navigate, I want to pop up a `toast` to remind them that they are in a limited preview view and that they can't navigate further.

BUT toast requires an activity `Context`.

In order to make the `Context` available I assign a `context` to a variable (`appContext`)in the class's constructor as follows:

```
public class nonInteractiveWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean canBrowse = false;
    public Context appContext;

    public nonInteractiveWebViewClient(Context context) {
        appContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

        String host = Uri.parse(view.getUrl()).getHost();

        canBrowse = // logic here to determine whether to allow navigation

        if (canBrowse) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(appContext, appContext.getString(R.string.link_test_preview_only), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I create the `nonInteractiveWebViewClient` object in the calling `activity` I call it with `getApplicationContext()` to pass the `context` to the constructor.

Is this a bad idea?

As @sajjad has noted before, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` has access to a `view` and `getContext()` can be run on a view, so the `appContext` variable is redundant in this exmaple, however...

I am also intending to use this pattern in another class which houses a number of methods that are used by multiple activities and that needs access to the `activity` `context` in a number of it's methods. These methods are standalone functions that do not extend any existing methods that might have access to a `context`. Using the approach above in this other class will both simplify my code and cut down on the number of calls to `getApplicationContext` that the calling activities need to make, but I am concerned that it may cause a memory leak or something.

Is this a bad approach?

*(When answering, please appreciate that I am an engineer and while I have some understanding of the underlying theories of programming I am by no means a CS. I like to write code to be as modular as possibel and to avoid duplication of code as much as possible, hence my tackling this issue this way.)*

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this approach.  When I do recyclerviews, I often pass in context to the adapter.

Comment: You are using your `toast` inside a method where there is a `view` object available. So why not using `view.getContext()` ?

Comment: @sajjad that works for the example given, thanks, but in the other class I have the methods are bespoke functions rather than extensions of existing methods and so do not have access to any context currently. So the general question still stands, are there any downsides to creating a reference to an `activity` `context` in an external class - my worry was memory leaks, but that's probably just due to my ignorance (and @KristyWelsh's comment suggests it it coudl be safe). I'll update the question to note your suggestion.

Comment: The applicationContext is basically the application. It will be around as long as the application runs, anyways. If you would use the activity context (or Activity, since Activity derives from Context) there might be a memory leak, but wouldn't be surprised if the Toast implementation would do a context.getApplicationContext() anyways.